# Extra Fields are not getting printed

Tags: php, excel, csv, cakephp, export-to-excel

Good afternoon

I am currently adding more features and functions to a judging system using CakePHP. I have looked for possible solutions as well as trying on my own to solve the problem but still I have not been able to figure out what is wrong with my code or database. I am trying to add an extra field to output it on a excel file from my database but it is not printed. Jcategory is filled in the database but will not be printed on the CSV file. All other fields get filled in the excel file except for my addition (Jcategory).

```
public function data2()
{ 
    $this->autoLayout = $this->autoRender = false;
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 600); //increase max_execution_time to 10 min if data set is very large
    //create a file
    $filename = "export_".date("Y.m.d").".csv";

    $csv_file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    header('Content-type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');

    //ALWAYS NEED RESULT
    $results = $this->Post->find('all');
    //$results = $this->Poster->find('all');

    // The column headings of your .csv file
    $header_row = array("id","poster_id","criteria1","criteria2","criteria3","criteria4","criteria5","criteria6","criteria7","criteria8","criteria9","criteria10","Jcategory","Test","Score","Author","category");
    fputcsv($csv_file,$header_row,',','"');
    // Each iteration of this while loop will be a row in your .csv file where each field corresponds to the heading of the column
    foreach($results as $result)
    {
        $authors = '';
        $authors = substr($authors,0,sizeof($authors)-3);
        $row = array(
            $result['Post']['id'],
            $result['Post']['poster_id'],
            $result['Post']['criteria1'],
            $result['Post']['criteria2'],
            $result['Post']['criteria3'],
            $result['Post']['criteria4'],
            $result['Post']['criteria5'],
            $result['Post']['criteria6'],
            $result['Post']['criteria7'],
            $result['Post']['criteria8'],
            $result['Post']['criteria9'],
            $result['Post']['criteria10'],
            $result['Post']['comments'],
            $result['Post']['jcategory'], //This is not being printed in the CSV File
            //Results are here at the bottom
            ($result['Post']['criteria1'])+($result['Post']['criteria2'])+($result['Post']['criteria3'])+($result['Post']['criteria4'])+($result['Post']['criteria5'])+($result['Post']['criteria6'])+($result['Post']['criteria7'])+($result['Post']['criteria8'])+($result['Post']['criteria9'])+($result['Post']['criteria10']),
            $result['poster']['author'],
            $result['poster']['category'],              
        );

        foreach($result['Author'] as $author){
            array_push($row, $author['id']);
            array_push($row, $author['middle']);
            array_push($row, $author['last']);
            array_push($row, $author['email']);
            array_push($row, $author['institution']);
            array_push($row, $author['department']);
            array_push($row, $author['type']);
        }
        fputcsv($csv_file,$row,',','"');
    }

    fclose($csv_file);
}
```

Comment: I don't know what fixed it but it works now.
In case anyone bumps into this problem I am writing the steps I took.
1.I made changes in the model to include a Jcategory Array
2.I added the field in the database.
3.Changed debug to 3

If anyone can explain why it worked that would be great.

Thank you